# How to allow the particular calls to ring and others to be silent?

Tags: android

I want to create an android app which is based on incoming calls.

I should receive incoming calls when important persons call, but if other persons call my phone should be silent.

Since I am new to android it is very tough for me.

Comment: i didnt tried anything my doubt is wheather it is possible or not.@SilentKiller.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be four steps to achieve your requirement.

1. Get Incoming Number
2. Compare it with your data(which can be store in database or in shared preference)
3. Make ring silent

**Get Incoming Number  :**

You need to create a `Broadcast receiver` say `CallReceiver` assign its action in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in that broadcast you need to add `PhoneStateListener` to your TelephonyManager, PhoneStateListener having override `onCallStateChanged()` with Number parameter. Thats it.

*CallReceiver.Java*

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String Number) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, Number);
                System.out.println("Number: " + Number);
                // Compare your number to from this `Number` if it is found in you list then make ring state RINGER_MODE_NORMAL 
                // else make it to RINGER_MODE_SILENT
                if (Number found in list) {
                    // to make Ring state silent
                    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                } else {
                    // to make Ring state Normal (Ringable)
                    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                }
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

**Make Ring silent :**

```
AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<!--This part is inside the application-->
<receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create new java class and name it PhoneCallReceiver

```
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.util.Log;

     public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing
private String[] impNumber = new String[8];private String[] impNumber = new String[8]; // you can give 8 number for more replace 8 with any number you can alse use other method for contact save and read FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file); to read and write value etc

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    impNumber[0]="342342323";
    impNumber[1]="234234234";
    impNumber[7]="2342343544";
    String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    int state = 0;
    if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
    } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
    }


    onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);

}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected  void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start){
   if(impNumber[0].compareTo(number)!=0||impNumber[1].compareTo(number)!=0||impNumber[7].compareTo(number)!=0){
    Log.e("Call Received" , "Number = "+ number);
    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}
};
protected  void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start){
    Log.e("Call Answered" , "Number = "+ number);
};
protected  void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){
    Log.e("Call Ended" , "Number = "+ number);
    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
};

protected  void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){
    Log.e("Missed" , "Number = "+ number);
    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
};

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){

                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());

            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Silent ringtone and assign it to certain contacts while the important contacts will have a non-silent ringtone.